# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-11

I am trying to run my tests with Maven, but I am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project MarkitWireCheck:
Compilation failure
No compiler is provided in this environment. 
Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

What I did was:

1. Open the project in cmd: cd C:\Users\MIRABR\eclipse-workspace\MarkitWireCheck
2. execute MVN:

   ```
   mvn test -Dtest=MKTWireComparisonTest#compareMKTWireIRS#compareMKTWireIRS
   ```

   (In this case executing just one test this class)

This is my config:

JDK used: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot
[image]

[image]

Execution Enviroment
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Comment: What's on your `Installed JREs` preference page? Also, the `Execution Environments` preference page in the screen shot is for mapping environments to entries on the `Installed JREs` page. It's not for choosing an environment

Comment: javac : 11.0.10  and JAVA Home: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\bin

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not point to the `bin` directory, but to the parent dir instead (`C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot`).

Comment: Ok, I have changed this but still with error. Another suggestion?

Comment: Your project will also have properties including an "Installed JRE", make sure it's not overridden there.  Right click on the project and select Properties